# Display video as splash Screen ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, splash-screen

i am trying to display video as the splash screen using this [Tutorial](https://www.grzegorowski.com/ionic-3-pwa-browser-splash-screen/). I am able to do css and add images but i can not use video as the splash screen.

MY code in index.html

```
  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app>
    <!-- custom splash screen (non-angular component) -->
    <div id="splash-screen" class="splash">
      <video autoplay muted loop webkit-playsinline playsinline src="assets/splash/Splash_Reduced.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </ion-app>
```

The splash screen is present but the video is broken or not available.

Comment: how lengthy is you video? did you try using animated gif as a video?

Comment: Hello @SergeyRudenko, the video is of about 7 seconds. No, i have not tried that yet. using a gif, i think, would cause a responsiveness issue for larger devices

Comment: have you got proper solution. it tried but not working properly in android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IONIC does not let us remove the default splash screen. The white blank screen will display for a while in android and the default splash screen is required for IOS.

SO, THE ONLY OPTION I FOUND IS USING TWO SPLASH SCREENS.

The default static splash screen and then the animated splash screen for the same logo. :)

I know it is not good practice. But after long searching and trying, I got to this solution.